# Still Got error 'TokenMismatchException ' in laravel V5.4 when form submit with post method:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am beginner in `laravel V5.4`and i already set basic configuration.

I make a registration form but Got error `TokenMismatchException` when form submit with post method in controller.

Thanks in advance.

I have following code.

View FIle:

```
<form method="post" style="margin: 20% 40%;" action="{{ action('UserController@insert_record')}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>

                <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="LastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="Gender" checked="checked" value="Male"/>
                    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Insert" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

Routes/Web.php

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/insert_employer','UserController@insert_record');
```

app/Http/Middelware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

 class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  /**
  * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
  *
  * @var array
  */
   protected $except = [
    //
  ];




 }
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use DB;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\employers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
   $users = employers::all();
   return view('user_view',['users'=>$users]);
}

public function add_employer(){
   return view('add_employer');
}



  public function insert_record(){
   echo '<pre>';print_r($_GET); echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);exit;

 }


 }
```

Comment: What is your error? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 enforces CSFR token authentication in middleware by default.If you are submit form using post method its best to place the CRSF middle ware on per route basis rather than placing it as a global middleware.

```
/**
* The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $middleware = [
  'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class',
  'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class',
  'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class',
  'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class',
  'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class',
  //comment out to avoid CSRF Token mismatch error
  // '\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class',,
];

/**
* The application's route middleware.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class',
   'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class',
   'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class',
   'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class',
   'api' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ApiMiddleware::class',
   'csrf' => 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class'// add it as a middleware 
   route
```

And  Go to `\Http\Controllers\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` and
in the `protected $except` add your route to be excluded from this verification. Example:

```
protected $except = [
    'user*'
];
```

Make sure that your php files that not start with empty line or an empty space before the opening `<?php`  tag! It cost me much trouble. Including that above!

And I think that's it. I hope it will work for you!!

Comment: It's solved but  Is it possible to without disable csrf token middelware?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you place `dd(request()->all());` at the beginning of `insert_record()`

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: something with not able to comment but still wanna help him.

Comment: @joeri Got error 'TokenMismatchException' at the beginning of insert_record().

Comment: try use `{!! csrf_token() !!} ` or remove the full input and use `{{ csrf_field() }}` hopefully one of the options will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Move your csrf_token outside of input:

```
<form action="">
{{  csrf_token() }}
<table>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried with '{{ csrf_token() }}' but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
  {!! csrf_field() !!}

  ...rest of the form body
</form>
```

Comment: I tried with '{!! csrf_field() !!}' but still got same error.

Comment: See if this helps:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-form-token-doesnt-match-session-token